# Javascript Function always returns wrong value, although variable had correct values before

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns the highest value of an attribute in an xml file

The Value returned is always 0, so I think the value under the JQuery function doesnt know what happens inside of it. Here is the function:

```
function findHighestValue(url,attr){
var highestValue = 0;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("achievement").each(function(){
             var value = $(this).find(attr).text();
             value = value*1;//typecast
             console.log("value: "+value);//shows correct value
             console.log("highestValue in ajax: "+highestValue);//shows correct value
             if (value >= highestValue){
                 highestValue = value;
                 console.log("Value higher highesValue detected!");//works as intended
             }

        });
    }
});
console.log("Highest Value: "+highestValue);// is 0 again
return highestValue;//always returns 0
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it's an ajax request the last two lines are hit before the lines inside the success method.

You cannot return a value from an ajax request unless you set `async: false`

You need to process the value via the success callback rather than trying to return it.

Comment: I learned my lesson, it makes totally sense. I set the async to false and now it works as intendted. Thank you!

Comment: @dan I don't advise setting async to false though as this will freeze the browser if your ajax request takes a long time. Much better to use the callback function to perform your logic.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is `asynchronous`, thus it doesn't wait for your `$.ajax()` call before calling `console.log()`, hence the wrong value. So you are right in the sense that `doesnt know what happens inside of it`

To tackle this, you can either place the rest of your function's logic inside `success` property of your `$.ajax` call or set `async: false`, be warned though that your browser will "freeze" a bit when `$.ajax()` happens